# Javascript Variable issue hitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
 let data;

     if(post.images.some(img => img._id == doc_id)) {
        post.images.forEach(function(e,i){
          if (post.images[i]._id == doc_id) { 
             data = ..... // if i defined here const data then i know its block scope will be access within this block only
            let isData = false;
            if (data.length === post.images[i].data.length) {
              data.push(myId);
              isData = true;
            }
          post.images[i].data = data

          }
          })
     } else {
       data = ..... // if i defined here const data then i know its block scope will be access within this block only        let isData = false;
        if (data.length === post.data.length) {
          data.push(myId);
          isData = true;
        }
        post.data = data;

     }

     res.out(data)
```

Getting errror Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
I know its getting problem from the loop i tried to fix with using return keyword but doesn't get success though.

How can i fix this warning problem is there any other way to fix this please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with returning the data;

```
if(post.images.some(img => img._id == doc_id)) {
            post.images.forEach(function(e,i){
              if (post.images[i]._id == doc_id) { 
                 data = ..... // if i defined here const data then i know its block scope will be access within this block only
                  let isData = false;
                  if (data.length === post.images[i].data.length) {
                    data.push(myId);
                    isData = true;
                  }
                 post.images[i].data = data
                 return data;
               } 
            })
         }
```